# Recursive window.scrollTo doesn't work in FireFox. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am using this function to "onclick" scroll page down:

```
function moveDown(arg) {
    smooth = setTimeout(moveDown, 10);
    if(!isFirefox){     ///// This works good for Chrome
         window.scrollTo(0, window.pageYOffset + 1);
    }
    if(isFirefox){    /// Does not work in FireFox
         console.log(window.pageYOffset) /// Every iteration returns 0
         window.scrollTo(0, window.pageYOffset + 1);
         console.log(window.pageYOffset) /// Every iteration returns 1
    }
```

The logic: Every iteration we increase pageYOffset by 1 px, but in FireFox every time it's 0 again. Thanks!

I post my full code because i can't find a problem by myself.

```
function moveDown(arg) {
    offset = parseFloat(timeline.style.width) * 7100 / 100;
    setTimeout(function() {  /// 1 ms - time to calculate offset
        window.scroll(0, offset);
    }, 1);
    if ( typeof arg === 'undefined') {  /// makes argument optional
        arg = true;
    }
    if (arg) {
            smooth = setTimeout(moveDown, 10); // Timeout makes recursive calls 
            if (window.pageYOffset > 7100) {
                story.pause();
                isPlaying = false;
                enable_scroll();
                animateTimeLine(false);
                clearTimeout(smooth);
                playButton.style.display = "block";
                pauseButton.style.display = "none";

            }
            if(!isFirefox){
                window.scrollTo(0, window.pageYOffset + 7408 / (story.duration * 47));
            }
            if(isFirefox){
                console.log(window.pageYOffset);
                window.scrollTo(0, window.pageYOffset + 7408 / (84 * 47));
                console.log(window.pageYOffset);
            }
    }
    if (arg == false) {
        clearTimeout(smooth);
    }
}

playButton.onclick = function() {
    moveDown();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle of an example demonstrating how the above code is used?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a scrollbar in Firefox? You must make sure that the browser can scroll. Without space it won't work.

This code scrolls down every 200ms by 1px, tested and works in Firefox v25:

```
<html>
<body onload="window.scrollTo(0,0); smooth = setInterval(moveDown, 200);">
<div style="height:2000px;">scroll</span>
<script>
function moveDown() {
     console.log(window.pageYOffset);
     window.scrollTo(0, window.pageYOffset + 1);
     console.log(window.pageYOffset);
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I see that your code is working, but i can't find why mine don't. I have added more code, can you check it?

Comment: The first timeout undoes what happens inside if (!isFirefox) and (isFirefox) - are you sure you want to call that - it looks like you want to have this in your initialization call. Call this just once at the start somewhere else. When you remove this it scrolls down by some pixels each time. Otherwise, you are depending on the variables timeline.style.width and story.duration, whereby if timeline.style.width does not change, the Y scroll position is at a constant value. On the other hand, if story.duration does not change, scrolling still happens as long as (7408 / (story.duration * 47) is > 0